# Move "show removed posts" to the top of the reputation tab

Tags: feature-request, reputation

"show removed posts" is at the bottom of the page now, it's too difficult to see for newbies. It should be moved to the top of the page.

Comment: Being unobtrusive is kinda by-design here. Is there a reason we should be encouraging new users to focus on the rep-effect their deleted posts is having?

Comment: My story: I found my reputation was decreased without downvote, and I can't see the reason in the reputation tab, so I asked a question here ... the answer is I deleted a post.